# Select/delete word inside brackets which inside quotes

Tags: ideavim

Small question about vim mode in PhpStorm. I have this strings

```
if ($newGroupName) {
    echo "<h3>{ $t->groupName }</h3>";
    echo '<div>';
}
```

I want to replace `$t->groupName` with `newGroupName`, what would be the correct shortcut? All shortcuts I've tried selects both lines between if brackets.

Comment: Can you take a look at this https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#a-pair

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Vim.

Comment: @romainl And why is that?

Comment: You don't use Vim.

Comment: But this question related to vim

Answer (score 3):

Use **ci{** which means: change what inside the curly brackets

Comment: This will change both the lines

Comment: That's what I meant. It deletes both lines between curly braces in if block

Comment: For me this is working (i.e. only `$t->groupName` is deleted). However, I am using vim on windows right now, maybe it behaves a bit different on other systems?

Comment: I am using vim mode for idea on windows. Maybe that's problem. Vim mode bahave differ from original vim

Comment: Put the cursor on `groupName` and do `ci{newGroupName<Esc>` or `ciB...` or `ciW...`. If none of them work, file a bug report on that plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

To change all inside next bracket you can add this on your .ideavimrc file:

```
nmap <leader>p f)ci(
```

- the `f)` is to go on next `)`
- then change all inside with `ci(`

note: if nothing is on the bracket you can just type `i` to Insert.